# Is it possible to enlarge the tip of the progress bar in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

[image: a]

Is it possible to make the progress tip (the end that has been shown in the image) larger or just different?

Here is my CSS code for the progress bar:

```
.progress-bar{
-fx-accent: aquamarine;
}

.progress-bar .bar{
-fx-background-insets: 0;
-fx-padding: 2px;
-fx-background-radius: 0px;
}

.progress-bar .track{
-fx-background-radius: 0px;
-fx-border-radius: 0px;
-fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use CSS I would use linear-gradient.

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine 90%, red 90%);
}
```

You can modify the % of the gradient stop to make the tip longer (or shorter). You can also use px instead of % if you prefer a fix size tip.

**Update**

If you need a higher tip you can't do it using css. Instead, you could do this:

```
    StackPane progressPane = new StackPane();

    progressPane.setMaxWidth(340);
    progressPane.setMaxHeight(44);
    progressPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    progressPane.getStyleClass().add("tip-progress-bar");

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.setPrefWidth(300);
    progressBar.setPrefHeight(8);

    StackPane tip = new StackPane();
    tip.setMinHeight(18);
    tip.setMaxWidth(6);
    tip.getStyleClass().add("tip");

    tip.translateXProperty().bind(progressBar.widthProperty()
            .multiply(progressBar.progressProperty())
            .subtract(tip.widthProperty()));

    progressPane.getChildren().setAll(progressBar, tip);
```

And the CSS:

```
.tip-progress-bar {
    -fx-padding: 18;
    -fx-background-color: slategray;
}

.tip-progress-bar > .tip {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.tip-progress-bar > .progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: aquamarine;/*linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine 90%, red 90%);*/
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.tip-progress-bar > .progress-bar > .track {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

And the result:

[image: TipProgressBar]

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer and I know very little `CSS`, but doesn't `linear-gradient` just change the color from beginning to end? If so, how does that enlarge the tip of the progress bar?

Comment: I want to make the tip larger as in increase only the height of the tip

Comment: Sedrik, a linear gradient to the right with one color stop in X% and then starting with different color in the same X% will keep the first X% on the left with the first color and the  last X% on the right with a different color.

Comment: I think that it is not possible to change the height of the tip of the bar with css. AK222 would need to implement a custom progressBar or a progressBarSkin respectively.